# DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name() in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sample code from http://phil-sqltips.blogspot.com/2015/07/beware-of-empty-partitions.html and I'd like to understand this xmlgen sql.

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT   table_owner
       , table_name
       , partition_name
       , TO_NUMBER (EXTRACTVALUE (XMLTYPE (DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml ('SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_exist FROM '
                                                             || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name (str => table_owner)
                                                             || '.'
                                                             || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name (str => table_name)
                                                             || ' PARTITION ('
                                                             || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name (str => partition_name)
                                                             || ') WHERE ROWNUM <= 1'
                                                              )
                                          )
                                , '/ROWSET/ROW/ROWS_EXIST'
                                 )
                   ) AS rows_exist
    FROM all_tab_partitions
   WHERE table_owner = 'WH'
     AND table_name IN ('POINT_OF_SALE_FACTS')
ORDER BY table_owner
       , table_name
       , partition_position
)
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '
     || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name (str => table_owner)
     || '.'
     || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name (str => table_name)
     || ' DROP PARTITION '
     || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name (str => partition_name)
     || ';' AS stmt
    , t.*
FROM t
WHERE rows_exist = 0
;
```

I've found most of them except this, 
`DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name (str => table_owner)`.
What is the syntax of arrow in `(str => table_owner)` inside of enquote_name? 
I found this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#BABDEHBC but there is no such arrow syntax, and couldn't find web sites for this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That's the **named parameter** syntax. [Here's the relevant documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-A5DA8CF5-1BCC-4ABE-9B68-DB593FF1D2CC). So `str => table_name` says to set the `str` parameter to `table_name`.

In this case, it isn't necessary, since `str` is the first parameter for `DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_NAME`. So you could omit it and just call `DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_name(table_owner)`.

But in some cases it can be very useful. For example, when there are multiple optional parameters (with defaults) and you only want to specify one of them. Or when you want to clarify the purpose of a parameter by displaying the parameter name next to the value.